# What does "it was nothing to how Harry felt." mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> ... And if the Dursleys were unhappy to have him back for the holidays, **it was nothing to how Harry felt**.

Normally, I see the phrase "**it was nothing to**" + **sb**, but here it's followed by "**how Harry felt**". So, I don't quite understand what it means. Is it a normal usage? What's the whole sentence trying to convey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence might make more sense to you with an added word:

> And if the Dursleys were unhappy to have him back for the holidays, it
>   was nothing ***compared*** to how Harry felt.

The meaning of the sentence is that Harry was far more unhappy about the situation than the Dursleys.

Comment: +1.  In  19th century texts you will encounter *was **as** nothing to X* with the same meaning of "compared to"